# Delete AD B2C Tenant Powershell

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, powershell-4.0, azure-powershell

I want to delete an AD B2C Tenant and all associated resources with it (applications, b2c policies, users etc). Is it possible to delete the tenant and associated resources with powershell?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You can delete your resources using Powershell but the tenant/directory itself needs to be deleted through the Azure Portal.

View these instructions for detailed information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-delete-howto

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureadb2c/2017/06/23/delete-b2c-tenant/